# What happened to "ms-appx" to load embedded Image sources in Xamarin?

Tags: image, xamarin, embedded-resource

In WPF and UWP, I could create an Image with a local resource like this:

```
    <Image Source="ms-appx:///MyDll/MyFolder//Folder.png"/>
```

This doesn't seem to work anymore in Xamarin.  What's the replacement for accessing embedded images (.bmp, .jpg, etc)?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows#embedded-images

Answer (score 0):

> To embed an image in a project, right-click to add new items and
>   select the image/s you wish to add. By default the image will have
>   Build Action: None; this needs to be set to Build Action:
>   `EmbeddedResource`.

The code to load an embedded image simply passes the `Resource ID` to the `ImageSource.FromResource` method as shown below:

```
var embeddedImage = new Image { Source = ImageSource.FromResource("xxx.jpg", typeof(EmbeddedImages).GetTypeInfo().Assembly) };
```

In xaml, add a custom xmlns to the XAML, using the correct namespace and assembly values for the project:

```
   xmlns:local="clr-namespace:xxxx;assembly=xxxx"

   <Image Source="{local:ImageResource xxx.jpg}" />
```

Refer: [embedded-images](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows#embedded-images)